# Aardvark Control Center wants TLS/SSE2 Library

Tags: centos, executable

Environment: 
CentOS 7.1 64-bit using Intel i7-4771 
Gnome 3 shell

I downloaded the Aardvark Control Center (Total Phase) and tried to execute the controlctr bash file, however I received the error message "Unable to execute application". I am not sure the problem is with the vendor, Total Phase, but rather I am thinking the issue is with something in Linux.

I searched the web and came up with [this link](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/error-unable-to-execute-application-4175417543/) for troubleshooting. The forum post was quite helpful. Aardvark Control Center is a 32-bit application, which in this case will run on a 64-bit i7 build of CentOS 7. The command "file controlctr.bin" shows a standard ELF format. I am copying and pasting from the forum post, but the actual line was similar, if not identical.

```
ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

"$ldd controlctr.bin" shows lines very similar to the forum post, namely

```
linux-gate.so.1 => (0xffffe000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb76fe000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i686/libpthread.so.0 (0xb76e4000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i686/libc.so.6 (0xb7566000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb771f000)
```

I ran strace -o  controlctr.bin.

The log shows that the problem is a missing tls sub-directory off of the Linux directory. In particular, the loader tries to find quite a few SSE2 libraries, which of course do not exist in the ZIP file. The log is littered with "No such file or directory" error messages on each of the SSE2 library calls; hence the eventual error message. Here is the relevant portion of the log file.

```
readlink("/proc/self/exe", "/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-"..., 1023) = 76
execve("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/controlctr.bin", ["controlctr.bin"], [/* 47 vars */]) = 0
brk(0)                                  = 0x9214000
mmap2(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xfffffffff76ed000
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/i686/sse2/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/i686/sse2", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/i686/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/i686", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/sse2/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/sse2", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/tls", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/i686/sse2/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/i686/sse2", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/i686/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/i686", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/sse2/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/sse2", 0xffd3eb30) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/home/jmr/Downloads/control-ctr-serial-linux-i686-v3.83/linux", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
```

I searched the web for those libraries and help on this issue, but came up empty. I do know that SSE2 is a function of newer processors, which include the Intel i7 CPU, which is probably why the controlctr.bin file looks for those libraries.

I did find [this SSE2 question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224625/sse2-requirement-for-john-the-ripper) on the U&L forum.

To answer the questions posed on the SSE2.

```
[root@jmr-server1 linux]# cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep flags | tail -n 1
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
[root@jmr-server1 linux]# uname -a
Linux jmr-server1 3.10.0-229.11.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Aug 6 01:06:18 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@jmr-server1 linux]# gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar problem under Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit. I took your s-trace approach and started installing the i386 libraries one by one and trying the application again. After I installed a handful of libraries the gui started. It detected my device but did not have permissions [I had not installed the udev rules] so I just executed `controlctr.bin` as root. Now it works!

To install the i386 version of the libraries simply suffix the library name with :i386

For example, I had to install these [scraped from the end of running strace on controlctr.bin]:

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386

sudo apt-get install libpango-1.0-0:i386

sudo apt-get install libpangox-1.0-0:i386

sudo apt-get install libpangoxft-1.0-0:i386
```